# I did a proof for magic square of squares and perfect cuboid.

Tags: magic-square

I did the proof for non-existence of magic square of squares. I am looking great guidelines on preparation and submission for publication. the main areas what I want assistance is
 1. the format of proof (content)
 2. the best organization for publication.
 3. if it is good to prepare the proofs in one or separately
 4. if it is must to use latex to to prepare the proof
 5. if it is right to submit more than one organization/ privates
        Thanks

Comment: To be taken seriously by the mathematical community, I would strongly recommend you to use $\LaTeX$.

Comment: What about the proof?

Comment: And if it is simple enough to be posted here, it is probably false. We expect problems of this nature to require a highly complex solution, probably with heavy use of computation.l, to be solved.